# Where can I find good unit testing resources for EJB and J2EE?

Tags: unit-testing, jakarta-ee, junit, ejb-3.0

Which **online resources**, **tutorials** or **books** can you recommended to get started with unit testing J2EE / EJB3 applications?

So far I have found [ejb3unit](http://ejb3unit.sourceforge.net/), [Jakarta Cactus](http://jakarta.apache.org/cactus/) (retired 2011/08) and the [Maven Cargo plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin). It would be helpful if there are complete working examples, ready to run.

Target containers are the open source products [GlassFish](http://glassfish.java.net/), [JBoss](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/) and [Apache OpenEJB](http://openejb.apache.org/).

Comment: Do you really mean unit testing or integration/functional testing?

Comment: Yes! Both!! The more the merrier ... :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[EJB Unit Testing with Eclipse and OpenEJB](http://www.vimeo.com/6149008)
[Article on Testing EJB](http://onjava.com/onjava/2003/02/05/automate_ejb.html)
[Glassfish EJB 3.0 Unit testing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFMxRTPO7FA)
[JUnitEE Tutorial](http://www.junitee.org/tutorial.html)
[Effective Unit Testing EJB 3.0 with OpenEJB](http://magnus-k-karlsson.blogspot.com/2009/07/effective-unit-testing-ejb-30-with.html)
[JUnitEE IBM Tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/07/0102_woldemichael/)

Answer (score 4):

The next version NetBeans 6.8 includes a nice new feature: it [generates Unit-Tests for EJB 3.1 with Embeddable Container code](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/two_amazing_netbeans_6_8beta).

```
@Test
public void testHello() throws Exception {
  System.out.println("hello");
  HelloService instance = (HelloService)javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer().getContext().lookup("java:global/classes/HelloService");
  String expResult = "";
  String result = instance.hello();
  assertEquals(expResult, result);
  // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
  fail("The test case is a prototype.");
}
```

Comment: +1 For using the embedded API (and GlassFish!). See http://blogs.sun.com/alexismp/entry/testing_ejb_3_1_s

Answer (score 2):

[EJB out-of-container testing](http://wernli.nine.ch/web/guest/45) by Erwann "Airone" Wernli

Answer (score 0):

[JSFUnit](http://labs.jboss.com/jsfunit/) is "a test framework for JSF applications. It is designed to allow complete integration testing and unit testing of JSF applications using a simplified API. JSFUnit tests run inside the container, which provides the developer full access to managed beans, the FacesContext, EL Expressions, and the internal JSF component tree. At the same time, you also have access to parsed HTML output of each client request."

Answer (score 0):

There is nice [book](http://www.manning.com/koskela/) on TDD written by [Lasse Koskela](http://lassekoskela.com/)

It has a free to download web extra based on [EJB testing](http://www.manning-source.com/books/koskela/online_bonus_ch13.pdf).Grab it and roll up your sleeves.