# Best current framework for unit testing EJB3 / JPA

Tags: java, unit-testing, jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

Starting a new project using EJB 3 / JPA, mainly stateless session beans and batch jobs.  I've used JUnit in the past on standard Java webapps and it seemed to work pretty well.  In EJB2 unit testing was a pain and required a running container such as JBoss to make the calls into.  Now that we're going to be working in EJB3 / JPA I'd like to know what companies are using to write and run these tests.  Are Junit and JMock still considered relevant or are there other newer frameworks that have come around that we should investigate?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IMHO, yes they are still relevant.

With EJB3, you can test you EJB either like regular POJO, or as managed bean using an embedded EJB container.

Same for JPA, you can either embed a JPA implementation for your test and use an in-memory database, or you can mock the data layer completely.

For my last EJB project I had written a bit of [glue code](http://www.ewernli.com/web/guest/45) to test the EJB because embedded EJB container were not mature enough, but now I would go for an embedded EJB container + JUnit.

A few resources

- Blog post: [How to unit test EJB 3 in 0.8 seconds](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/how_to_unit_test_ejb)
- SO question: [Good unit testing resource for EJB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733805/where-can-i-find-good-unit-testing-resources-for-ejb-and-j2ee)

But there are many others easily findable

Answer (score 8):

For **unit testing**, you can use JUnit, TestNG and your favorite mocking framework ([EasyMock](http://www.easymock.org/), [Mockito](http://mockito.org/), [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/), [JMockit](http://jmockit.org/), [JMock](http://www.jmock.org/)).

For **integration testing**, you could start/stop an embeddable container (JBoss, OpenEJB, GlassFish v3) from your tests. Or, have a look at [Arquillian](http://community.jboss.org/docs/DOC-14376), a very recent new player for integration testing of Java EE applications:

> The mission of the Arquillian project is to provide a simple test harness that developers can use to produce a broad range of integration tests for their Java applications (most likely enterprise applications). A test case may be executed within the container, deployed alongside the code under test, or by coordinating with the container, acting as a client to the deployed code.
>
> To avoid introducing unnecessary complexity into the developer's build environment, Arquillian integrates transparently with familiar testing frameworks (e.g. JUnit 4, TestNG 5), allowing tests to be launched using existing IDE, Ant and Maven test plugins without any add-ons.

Also check [Improving the Testability of Java EE With Arquillian 1.0.0 Alpha 1 Released](http://java.dzone.com/articles/arquillian-making-integration) and the [Arquillan](http://community.jboss.org/en/arquillian) space. Looks interesting IMO.

Comment: I would classify testing a single EJB against an embedded container as also being a unit test. IMO integration testing is more using Selenium etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can go for Apache [OpenEJB](http://openejb.apache.org/) which is a lightweight EJB3.0 implementation that can be embedded into TestNG.

[Here](http://www.texient.com/2010/03/unit-testing-ejb3-hibernate-using.html) you can find sample code which uses OpenEJB, TestNG and jMockIt for unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

One option is also to use Spring, but of course your architecture will then be based on Spring on the runtime as well. The reason I like Spring is that it is easy to inject what ever mock data and objects is needed during the testing phase as you can annotate in the JUnit test case which context file to use:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:test-context.xml"})
public class MyClassTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyClass myClass;

    @Test
    public void testMyMethod() {....}
```

But if you don't want to use Spring anyway, then this is quite irrelevant :) On the other hand, it is very easy to switch out from Spring afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Arquillian. 
With Arquillian you have the options to test normal EJBs, or CDI beans. You could run your test agains an enbedded, managed, or remote EE container. The Arquillian project is continuously maintanced...

However it is not always so easy to make your first arquillian test run. You might have problem finding the dependencies for the correct arquillian version and container version. I have posted a tutorial serial about this. But to not make me suspious of promoting, the link is not posted here.  If you   like you could just google "Tutorial EJB3 Integration Test with Arquillian part1".