# How to initialize an EJB's EntityManager in a JUnit test?

Tags: hibernate, junit, ejb, entitymanager

I'm trying to write JUnit tests for a stateless session bean that has an injected EntityManager:

```
@Stateless
public class MyServiceBean implements MyService, ... {
@PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    ....
```

Of course, without doing anything, em remains null in the flow of the test...

The tests should run standalone (NOT in a Java EE container).

How do I do that please? (simple solutions will be most appreciated :-)

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer is don't do that, if you want to have persistence context injected like in the real working application, use embedded/external server for testing. More info about testing EJBs and JPA you can find here: [Best current framework for unit testing EJB3 / JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485635/best-current-framework-for-unit-testing-ejb3-jpa)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your data access logic (criteria code, jpql queries, etc) what I'd do is using [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/). There is no need to mock the EntityManager or have a Java EE container and it integrates nicely with the build process.

Answer (score 0):

You mock it with Mockito. You add dependency of Mockito and with `@MockitoJUnitRunner` annotation on your class, you can `@Mock EntityManger entityManager` and `@InjectMocks MyService service` in your unit test. You will stub it like `when(entityManager.findById(id)).thenReturn(somethingIWantItToReturn);`.