# Testing EJBs with transactions without deploying it into a container?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, ejb

My Java EE application contains EJBs which handles intermodular transactions. I need to test all these EJBs using Unit Tests. I can test the functions without intermodular dependencies. Is there a way to test EJBs without deploying it into any container?

Answer (score 2):

We are having a look at arquillian. It seems to be the most common solution.

Comment: By using Arquillian, can we test the product in the build time without deploying it.

Comment: You use Arquillian to run JUnit tests in a container of your choice. Your unit tests are effectively deployed, but this is very fast because they're typically tiny deployments.

Answer (score 0):

Well, another option is to use some sort of embedded EJB-Container like OpenEJB or Glassfish.

Nonetheless i would prefer the arquillian approach too. 
Testing intermodular ejb-interactions looks more like some sort of integration test to me. 
Therefore i would rather stick with a setup which resembles the runtime environment your EJBs will be deployed too instead of 'rebuilding' it with an embedded EJB-Container.

You might want to have a look at:

[Best current framework for unit testing EJB3 / JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485635/best-current-framework-for-unit-testing-ejb3-jpa)

too.