# Unit test for EJB3

Tags: jpa, maven, ejb-3.0

I would like to setup unit and integration for ejb3 (entity/jpa). I'm using Eclipse, Maven, and Jonas server. It seems that easybeans is what I need for integration test.
Where can I find some sample project?
Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find good unit testing resources for EJB and J2EE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733805/where-can-i-find-good-unit-testing-resources-for-ejb-and-j2ee). Also, EasyBeans is an EJB 3 implementation - I don't see what that has to do with unit/integration  tests.

Comment: openejb is an ejb container also, isn't it? if I'm right, I don't see diffence between openejb and easybeans. Let me know if I'm wrong, I'm newbye to jee development.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the EJB embedded container: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/embedding_ejb_3_1_container